# SQL Server 2008 R2, separate regular and overtime hours by Department, Employee and Workdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I'm trying to write a report for HR that splits regular and overtime hours by department, employee and workdate and I'm really not sure how to even begin.

The following creates a temp table with a range of sample data that reflects the actual data I will work with.

```
-- Create Temp Tables --
CREATE TABLE #Employee_Hours
(
        emp_num     nvarchar(20)
        ,dept       nvarchar(20)
        ,shift      nvarchar(3)
        ,work_date  Date
        ,start_time DateTime
        ,hrs        Decimal(19,8)
);

-- Populate #Employee_Hours with sample hours
INSERT #Employee_Hours(emp_num, dept, shift, work_date, start_time, hrs)
VALUES ('W-C0001', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-22 06:30:00.000', 7.9)
      ,('W-C0001', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-24 06:45:00.000', 8.6)
      ,('W-C0001', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-26 08:00:00.000', 2.0)
      ,('W-C0001', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-26 10:00:00.000', 0.5)
      ,('W-C0001', 'Asmb', 'Day', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-26 11:00:00.000', 1.33333)
      ,('W-C0001', 'Shop A', 'Day', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-26 11:30:00.000', 5.5)
      ,('G-C0000', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-22 08:00:00.000', 4.5)
      ,('G-C0000', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-22 12:30:00.000', 4.0)
      ,('G-C0000', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-23', '2015-02-23 07:30:00.000', 8.25)
      ,('G-C0000', 'Admin', 'Day', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-24 08:30:00.000', 8.9)
      ,('W-R0000', 'Eng', 'Day', '2015-02-22', '2015-02-22 08:30:00.000', 8.02)
      ,('W-R0000', 'Eng', 'Day', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-24 09:30:00.000', 8.75)
GO

    SELECT * FROM #Employee_Hours

    DROP TABLE #Employee_Hours
```

The data table has five columns:

1. `emp_num` --Employee Number
2. `dept` --Transaction Department
3. `shift` --Transaction Shift
4. `work_date` --Work Date of the transaction
5. `start_time` --Start Time of the transaction
6. `hrs` --Total hours per transaction

Now, some of our employees will change departments through out the day, when they do they clock out of their old department and then clock back in under a different department.

Note the transactions for emp_num 'W-C0001', that employee has four transactions on work_date 02/26/2015. Our overtime is anything after 8 hours per work day is overtime, and here in lies my problem.

Summed up by department and work_date for emp_num 'W-C0001' the sample data would look like this:

```
 work_date  |  dept  | hrs
 02/26/2015   Admin    2.5
 02/26/2015   Asmb     1.3
 02/26/2015   Shop A   5.5
```

This adds up to 9.6 hours on work_date 02/26/2016, or 8 regular and 1.3 overtime. Now I need to allocate the 1.3 hours overtime to either the first or last department of the work_date, this overtime allocation is determined by the shift code, if it's 'Day' then allocate the overtime to the last department, else to the first department of the day.

This of course is complicated because the employee could be working 8.5 hours in department A, then switch to department B for another hour. The result would have to be 8 hours reg for dept A, .5 hours overtime for dept A and 1 hour overtime for department B.

The results I need from my final select statement using the above sample is:

```
  work_date   |  dept  |  hrs_reg  |  hrs_ot
 02/26/2015      Admin      2.5         0
 02/26/2015      Asmb       1.3         0
 02/26/2015      Shop A     4.2        1.3
```

**UPDATE**
I think I've got it thanks to @TommCatt. I'm using the `start_time` column to help decide which department get's the overtime. I added it to the sample data in my temp table.

I Modified his answer slightly and it seems to give me what I want. I included the `start_time` column and used it in a `CASE` expression to allocate the overtime to the `MAX(start_time)`.

```
WITH EmpOvertime
(
    emp_num
    ,dept
    ,shift
    ,work_date
    ,start_time
    ,hrs
    ,DailyTotal
    ,OTHours
)
AS
(
    SELECT h.emp_num
        ,h.dept
        ,h.shift
        ,h.work_date
        ,h.start_time
        ,h.hrs
        ,SUM(h.hrs) OVER(PARTITION BY h.emp_num, h.work_date)
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Sum(h.hrs) OVER(PARTITION BY h.emp_num, h.work_date) - 8 > 0
            THEN Sum(h.hrs) OVER(PARTITION BY h.emp_num, h.work_date) - 8
            ELSE 0
         END
    FROM #Employee_Hours AS h
)
SELECT emp_num
    ,dept
    ,shift
    ,work_date
    ,hrs
    ,DailyTotal
    ,CASE -- Only subract overtime from the last entry for the work day
        WHEN start_time = (SELECT MAX(h2.start_time)
                                FROM #Employee_Hours AS h2
                                WHERE h2.emp_num = ot.emp_num
                                    AND h2.work_date = ot.work_date)
        THEN hrs - OTHours
        ELSE hrs
    END AS RegHours
    ,CASE -- Only allocate overtime to the last entry for the work day
        WHEN start_time = (SELECT MAX(h2.start_time)
                                FROM #Employee_Hours AS h2
                                WHERE h2.emp_num = ot.emp_num
                                    AND h2.work_date = ot.work_date)
        THEN OTHours
        ELSE 0
    END AS OTHours
FROM EmpOvertime AS ot
ORDER BY ot.emp_num, ot.work_date;
```

Here are the results:

```
emp_num dept    shift work_date     hrs     DailyTotal  RegHours    OTHours
------- -----   ----  ----------    ---     ---         ---         ---
G-C0000 Admin   Day   2015-02-22    4.5     8.5         4.5         0.0
G-C0000 Admin   Day   2015-02-22    4.0     8.5         3.5         0.5
W-C0001 Admin   Day   2015-02-22    7.9     7.9         7.9         0.0
W-C0001 Admin   Day   2015-02-24    8.6     8.6         8.0         0.6
W-C0001 Admin   Day   2015-02-26    2.0     9.3         2.0         0.0
W-C0001 Admin   Day   2015-02-26    0.5     9.3         0.5         0.0
W-C0001 Asmb    Day   2015-02-26    1.3     9.3         1.3         0.0
W-C0001 Shop A  Day   2015-02-26    5.5     9.3         4.1         1.3
```

Note how the `RegHours` column for employee **'W-C0001'** for `work_date` **'2015-02-26'** now shows the full hours for all rows in that work_date, except for the last entry where it subtracts the OT. And same with the `OTHours` column, it's zero for rows in that work_date, except for the last one.

I can now use the Shift code to determine whether to allocate the OT to the first or last transaction of the work day.

I hadn't used `OVER(PARTITION BY )` until now, but was able to figure how how they work from TommCatt's answer.

Is there perhaps a cleaner way to allocate the OT to the last or first transaction based of the `start_time` then the `CASE` expression I'm using?

Comment: Do you need to do this in a query?  I'm sure it can be done, but it seems like it would be easier in code.

Comment: How do you determine which department is first in the day? Is there an ID that you didn't include which means lower ID, earlier?

Comment: @regeter, yes, sorry I forgot about it. There is a DateTime column named start_time that could be used to determine the first or last department in a work day.

Comment: @Jen R Yes, the query will feed an SSRS report.

Comment: @Paul Griffin I've tried a few things, a query where I sum up the hours by employee, department and work date into a temp table. But I have no idea how to proceed when it comes to splitting the regular and overtime from work days where one employee has multiple transactions under different departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know analytics, I'm not sure I can explain them to you. I'm pretty savvy about database concepts but analytics I just had to user over and over before they finally began to sink in. I still don't like using them because, while they are often handy, they require *sooo* much testing to make sure you're getting the right answer.

The idea is that you have to have a running total of hours worked for each employee over each particular day. Then have a column that ignores that running daily total until it exceeds 8 hours. Feed that into another query which splits the hours into regular and overtime.

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0895/2/0)</kbd>

```
with
EmpOvertime( emp_num, dept, shift, work_date, hrs, RunningHrs, OTHours )as(
    select  h.emp_num, h.dept, h.shift, h.work_date, h.hrs,
            Sum( h.hrs )over( partition by h.emp_num, h.work_date order by h.hrs ),
            case when Sum( h.hrs )over( partition by h.emp_num, h.work_date order by h.hrs ) - 8 > 0
                then Sum( h.hrs )over( partition by h.emp_num, h.work_date order by h.hrs ) - 8
                else 0
            end
    from    Employee_Hours  h
)
select  emp_num, dept, shift, work_date, hrs ClockedHrs, RunningHrs, hrs - OTHours RegHours, OTHours
from    EmpOvertime ot
order by ot.emp_num, ot.work_date;
```

I've exposed the raw total of the `Sum` from the CTE as RunningHrs so you can directly see the value being generated. Once you're comfortable with the query, you can remove it as it is not directly used in the final query.

This is not exactly what you asked for but you don't show any way to designate the first or last period of a shift. There is no way then to work that into the query. So the overtime hours just show up in the period where the daily total started exceeding 8 hours. I hope this is good enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I modified your code a bit and I think I got it working now. I've updated my question with the modified code. Going to do some more testing, if I run into issues I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, will not always work, but something like that:

```
SELECT work_date,
dept,
CASE WHEN ot.tot IS NOT NULL  THEN total - ot.tot ELSE total END AS s,
ot.tot

FROM  (
SELECT eh.work_date, 
eh.dept, 
eo.d,
SUM(eh.hrs) total,
eo.t
FROM #Employee_Hours eh
JOIN (
SELECT work_date,  SUM(hrs) t, MAX(dept) d
FROM #Employee_Hours
GROUP BY work_date
) eo
ON eo.work_date = eh.work_date
WHERE eh.work_date = '2015-02-26'
GROUP BY eh.work_date, eh.dept, eo.d, eo.t
) a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT  CASE WHEN t <= 8 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN d = dept THEN t-8 END END tot) AS ot
```

Comment: It works, but it's a little beyond my understanding of SQL so I don't know exactly how it works and what conditions will cause it to fail. I will have to see if I can figured out how it works, would you be able to explain your solution a bit? Specifically the two select statements inside the first FROM, and the CROSS APPLY, I've never used either.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is used just as a "shortcut", it would be the same if you replace  ot.tot with CASE WHEN t <= 8 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN d = dept THEN t-8 END END everywhere and remove CROSS APPLY. With CORSS APPLY it just looks nicer. The logic is to find extra hours for the date and extract them from the record. It is hard to identify from which record to extract these extra hours. The bad thing will happen when the overtime hours will be greater than the 'last' hours worked. Then you'll get negative amount.